# Copying (Drag & Drop) mutliple emails of Mail.app to Finder/Path Finder

Tags: mail.app, email

I sometimes copy (drag & drop) emails from Mail to Finder/Path Finder. But, when I try to copy multiple files outside Mail, I can't do that. I have to copy one by one.

Why is this? Is there any way to copy(drag & drop) multiple emails from Mail.app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know your emails from the default Apple Mail application in the following location: Macintosh HD/Users/(Your User Name)/Library/Mail/ - there will be some files in there, choose the folder that has the account with the emails you want. Then, click on the folder inside of the account's folder that contains your email's folder (inbox, sent, trash, etc.). Then, select the messages you want by using Shift-Click and drag them to the Finder. Hope this helps!